# T-SQL : Returning value between 2 characters

Tags: t-sql, substring, charindex

I am trying to return the text between 2 characters, an underscore and a dot.

To that end, I have been successful with the SQL below.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Filename, CHARINDEX('_', Filename)
, CHARINDEX('.',Filename) - CHARINDEX('_', Filename) + Len('.'))
```

However I have since found out that the filename string can contain 2 or more underscores.

How can I amend the above SQL to return the string between the LAST underscore and the dot?

Typically the filenames are :

- fileabc_draft_**v1**.pdf
- filedef_final_**v6**.pdf
- filezxz111_review_**v10**.pdf

In the above examples I would want to return :

- v1
- v6
- v10

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the string and apply similar logic

```
SELECT
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Filename),
                      CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Filename)) + 1,
                      CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Filename)) -
                          CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Filename)) - 1)) AS fragment
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Filename LIKE '%[_]%.%';
```

**Output:**

```
v1
v6
v10
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, the SQL worked in the demo but when I applied it to my script it gave me an "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." error. Is this because I am doing in T SQL?

Comment: @MarcusCamby I suspect that you have bad data in your table.  I will add a `WHERE` clause to ensure that you only try to parse legitimate filenames.

Answer (score 0):

A couple other ways depending on your data (note my comments):

```
-- sample data 
declare @table table([filename] varchar(100));
insert @table 
values ('fileabc_draft_v1.pdf'),('filedef_final_v6.pdf'),('filezxz111_review_v10.pdf');

-- if there's always 1 dot and 2 underscores:
select [filename], parsename(replace([filename], '_','.'),2)
from @table;

-- if what you are looking for is always formatted as "_v" followed by numbers
select [filename], a, b, v = substring([filename], b+1, a-(b+1))
from @table
cross apply (values (charindex('.', [filename]), charindex('_v', [filename]))) v(a,b);
```